# Angular showing component at home page only

Tags: angular, routes

I was having some problem when trying to show certain components at the home page of my Angular project. Here are the components in my home page aka app.component.html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top ">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">  
 <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-4">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-value="maincomponent" routerLink="main-cmp">Manage Expense</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-value="managecategory" routerLink="manage-category">Manage Category</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-value="newcomponent" routerLink="new-cmp">Login</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div ng-show="routeParam.page='#'">This is the extra div that only exists on home page. But it's outside the ng-view scope.</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<footer class="page-footer font-small">
  <hr class="col-md-3" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
  <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">© 2019 Copyright. All rights reserved.
  </div>
</footer>
```

My routing.ts:

```
  const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "main-cmp",
    component: MainCmpComponent
  },
  {
    path: "new-cmp",
    component: NewCmpComponent
  },
  {
    path: "manage-category",
    component: ManageCategoryComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [NgbModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I wanted to show the navigation bar and footer at all other pages but the div with dummy text only show at the home page. However, by doing this, the div is showing together with the navigation bar and footer at all other pages as well.

Any ideas on how to show the div only at the home page? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the div in the home page ?

Or you can use ngIf on your routerLink like

```
// mycomponent.component.ts
class MyComponent {
    constructor(public router: Router) {

    }
}

// mycomponent.component.html
<div *ngIf="router.url === '/some/route'">

</div>
```

Comment: My home page is the app.component.html

Comment: Any ideas on how to resolve this? Because by putting the div into the home page, it is showing in my other pages as well which I do not want it to show

Comment: use this 
<div *ngIf="router.url === '/'">

</div>

Answer (score 0):

In your app.component.html file you must leave only

```
<router-outlet><router-outlet/>
```

**all page under router will loaded by handler of router.**

A simple example that I use in my every projects

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Sidebar  -->
    <nav id="sidebar" class="active" *ngIf="isLogged">
        <div class="sidebar-header">
            HEADER ... 
        </div>

        <ul class="list-unstyled components">
            <li>
                <a routerLink="/XYZ">
                    <i class="fas fa-cog"></i>XYZ
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content  -->
    <div id="content">
        <div [hidden]="!showLoader" style="top: 30%; position: fixed; left: 50%;">
            <img src="/assets/loader.gif">
        </div>
        <router-outlet [hidden]="showLoader"></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But shouldn't the navigation bar, footer, header should be inside app.component.html together with the router tag? Since they will be appearing at all other pages as well

Comment: Is there anyway I can declare to show certain div when the url is localhost:4200/# which is the app.component.html?

Comment: yeah, content of app.component.html is shown in every page and the part of router-outle is replaced by the routed page's html component. I made only an example, you can replace navbar with your and add your footer and on half them add the <router-outlet>

Comment: for your home page make another component and leave under the router making only "/" path

Comment: I created a new page with path as "/" but I am getting this error message: Invalid configuration of route '/': path cannot start with a slash

Comment: replace your "/" with "**"

Comment: Nope that does not work. The component in the page with the path "*" is not showing upon first load

Comment: @hyperfkcb use this example for your router definition

const routes: Routes = [
 { path: 'example', component: ExampleComponent },
 { path: 'other', component: OtherComponent },
 { path: '**', component: HomeComponent }
];

Comment: Yeap that is exactly what I have changed

Comment: I realized it should be "" instead of "*" Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here how we use may be you can get an idea

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: GuestLayoutComponent, // here we say what is the parent should render below children
        children: [
            {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
            {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        component: AuthenticatedLayoutComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: 'profile',
                component: ProfileComponent,
                pathMatch: 'full',
                data: {
                    permissions: {
                        redirectTo: UNAUTHORIZED_ROUTE
                    }
                },
                canActivate: [NgxPermissionsGuard]
            },
            {
                path: 'dashboard',
                component: DashboardComponent,
                data: {
                    permissions: {
                        redirectTo: UNAUTHORIZED_ROUTE
                    }
                },
                canActivate: [NgxPermissionsGuard]
            },
        ]
    },
    {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];
```

app.component.html

```
<div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

guest-layout.component.html

```
<div id="guestLayout" class="guest-layout-page-wrapper">
     <app-header></app-header>

     <div class="guest-layout-content-wrapper">
         <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>

    <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

authenticated-layout.component.html

```
<div id="authenticated-wrapper">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar> //we use a sidebar component to navigate to other routes
    <div id="main-board" class="authenticated-layout-page-wrapper">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

in your routing.ts
using   '   instead of   "   .

exemple:

```
{
path: 'main-cmp',
component: MainCmpComponent },
```

and to save space:

```
{ path: 'main-cmp', component: MainCmpComponent },
```

Comment: Sorry but what you mean?

Comment: use a single rib instead of a double (sorry for my english)